# How to connect to HW device on IP address ending with .255?

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address, tcpip

I have HW device with web settings interface (similar principle like router, but it isn't router) and I changed the IP address of the device to .255.

I know it is an broadcast address now and I'm unable to connect to this device anymore. The device doesn't have factory reset button, so I have no other idea how to fix it.

Is there any possibility how to disable the broadcasting and use the 255 like "normal" IP address (temporary)? Or do you have any idea how solve it?

My router network setting: router 192.168.2.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily change your computer's netmask to a wider one, e.g. 255.255.0.0 will do the job.

It's **not** addresses which end in 255 that are 'broadcast' – it is the *last address of the subnet* that is 'broadcast'. That is, subnets larger than /24 will have plenty of normal addresses ending in 255, while subnets smaller than /24 will have broadcast addresses which *don't* end in 255, it all depends on the netmask being used.

So if you use 255.255.0.0 (aka /16) as the netmask, then only `x.y.255.255` will be the broadcast address and x.y.2.255 will not be.

(Yes, your and your device's netmasks will temporarily be mismatching, but this shouldn't make it any worse. Don't forget to return the configuration to original later, however.)

Comment: Thx a lot. it works!!